# Laravel UUID generation

Tags: php, laravel, uuid

I am trying to generate a UUID (not as primary key, just generate one) with the [laravel-uuid](https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid) package. The docs are pretty straightforward, so according to the readme file a UUID should be generated just by calling `$uuid = Uuid::generate();`, but it returns an empty object. (I also tried `$uuid = Uuid::generate(1);`)

I followed the installation instructions as provided there (nothing out of the ordinary), the app doesn't throw any errors, so I guess everything is right.

Alternative packages for this are also welcome.

Comment: try `echo Uuid::generate()` or `$uuid = Uuid::generate(); echo $uuid->string`

Comment: I second what @BenSwinburne said: looking at the [source](https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid/blob/master/src/Webpatser/Uuid/Uuid.php#L428) seems like you should be able to do `echo Uuid::generate()->time` to get back the v1 UUID. Or `->string` to get the string version.

Comment: Got it to work... turns out the object is returned empty if I try to return it with a response, and when I used $uuid->string it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 192, accepted):

After **laravel 5.6** a new helper was added to generate Universal Unique Identifiers (UUID)

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return (string) Str::uuid();

return (string) Str::orderedUuid();
```

The methods return a `Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid` object

The `orderedUuid()` method will generate a timestamp first UUID for easier and more efficient database indexing.

Comment: Valid for laravel 7 as well. Thanks

Comment: Works for Laravel 8 too.

Comment: Works for Laravel 9 as well.

Comment: Works for Laravel 10 as well.

Comment: Works for Laravel 11 as well.

Answer (score 59):

In Laravel 5.6+

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$uuid = Str::uuid()->toString();
```

Comment: You don't need toString()

Answer (score 9):

In laravel 9 and 10

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;


return (string) Str::uuid();
```

For primary key id  laravel 9 model import

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids;
```

and then add in your class

```
use HasUuids;
```

Answer (score 7):

Turns out I had to use `$uuid->string` to get the actual ID, the whole object shows empty if you try to return it in a json response.

Comment: You can add the uuid field as part of the casts section within the model
For my case, the id was the uuid field and to return the actual uuid as part of the response, I had to cast it as below.

`protected $casts = ['id' => 'string'];`

Answer (score 6):

It's possible that `$uuid` is empty because your system doesn't provide the right kind of entropy. You might try these library implementations for either a v4 or v5 UUID:

```
// https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122#section-4.4
function v4() {
    $data = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16, $secure);
    if (false === $data) { return false; }
    $data[6] = chr(ord($data[6]) & 0x0f | 0x40); // set version to 0100
    $data[8] = chr(ord($data[8]) & 0x3f | 0x80); // set bits 6-7 to 10
    return vsprintf('%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex($data), 4));
}

// https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122#section-4.3
function v5($name) {
    $hash = sha1($name, false);
    return sprintf(
        '%s-%s-5%s-%s-%s',
        substr($hash,  0,  8),
        substr($hash,  8,  4),
        substr($hash, 17,  3),
        substr($hash, 24,  4),
        substr($hash, 32, 12)
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks mate, I'll try this as a last resort, I wanted to use something built for laravel

Answer (score 3):

1. add column in table name 'Uuid', type 'char' length 36
2. create folder name 'Traits' inside Models folder
3. Create file  name Uuid.php inside Traits folder

Uuid.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Traits;

use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid as PackageUuid;

trait Uuid
{

    public function scopeUuid($query, $uuid)
    {
        return $query->where($this->getUuidName(), $uuid);
    }

    public function getUuidName()
    {
        return property_exists($this, 'uuidName') ? $this->uuidName : 'uuid';
    }

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getUuidName()} = PackageUuid::uuid4()->toString();
        });
    }
}
```

4. add 'use Uuid' inside your model

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this package will automatically generate and assign UUID field in your model, also can show and update by UUIDs key.

https://github.com/EmadAdly/laravel-uuid

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 9 you can use

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
 
return (string) Str::uuid();
```

Answer (score 0):

**for laravel < 5.6**

use  `DB::raw('uuid()');`

please have a look at below example

inside model

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


public static function boot(){
    parent::boot();
    $creationCallback = function ($model) {
        if (empty($model->{$model->getKeyName()}))
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = DB::raw('uuid()');
    };
    static::creating($creationCallback);
}
```

**Pros**

--You don't have to use any third-party plugin to get UUID in case you are using laravel < 5.6

**Cons**

after saving the data using ORM you need to query again to get the last inserted id otherwise you will get uuid().

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to use id and uuid columns so I created two columns in the table and just follow the laravel basics to insert uuid automatically in the table.

In Model File

```
/**
 *  Setup model event hooks
 */
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    self::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->uuid = (string) Str::uuid();
    });
}
```

In migration file

```
Schema::create('ekankotri.in', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->uuid('uuid');
});
```